# Vaadin Leaflet Editable in Vaadin Flow

Tags: leaflet, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am trying to use [V-Leaflet-Editable](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/v-leaflet-editable/3.0.0) in a Vaadin Flow 14 app.

I have added the below in the pom.xml

```
<repository>
      <id>osgeo-alt</id>
      <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
       <id>geomajas</id>
       <name>Geomajas Maven Repository</name>
       <url>http://maven.geomajas.org/(http://maven.geomajas.org/)</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>      
  <id>geotools</id>
  <name>Geotools repository</name>
  <!--<url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>-->
  <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geotools-releases/</url>
</repository>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
    <artifactId>v-leaflet-editable</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting this error in Eclipse: `The type com.vaadin.server.AbstractExtension cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`.

Is this version too old for Vaadin Flow 14? If yes, is there any alternative?

I only need to be able to draw a circle on the map.

Comment: 3.x branch of that add-on is built for Vaadin 8, so it relies on a rather different structure than Vaadin Flow uses. I pinged the author in case he has any plans for the mentioned 4.x branch, but I think currently there is only https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leafletjs-for-flow

I haven't used these myself so I don't know if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add-on version that you are trying to use if for Vaadin 8.x versions. Add-on architecture is totally different in Vaadin 14 that you are using, so it is not compatible, unless you wrap that component using Vaadin Multiplatform Runtime.

If you only need to draw circles using the API, you can use [a newer Leaflet integration](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leafletmap-for-vaadin). If you need to allow your end users to draw the circles on a map, then a similar Leaflet.Editable add-on for Vaadin 14 would be needed. I (the author of v-leaflet-editable add-on) don't have active plans to work on such, until I start a migration of my large hobby app to a newer Vaadin version, but if you master front-end technology, it should be rather easy to implement it by yourself or [purchase one](https://vaadin.com/company/contact).